# Informix open admin tool

Tags: informix

Now that OAT (open admin tool) for Informix no longer appears in the Informix installation package, has IBM or the community abandoned it? Is this still an active project? I have not found a strightforward answer to this question. Any good alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can still get Informix OpenAdmin Tool as part of the IBM Informix ClientSDK. However, you'll have to download an older version of the ClientSDK from IBM Passport Advantage. OAT will be deprecated at some point. The Informix development team is working on a alternative modern tool. Stay tuned and connected with the Informix community.